# Text with gradient in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

How would I extend `TextView` to allow the drawing of text with a gradient effect?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It doesn't appear possible to extend TextView to draw text with a gradient. It is, however, possible to achieve this effect by creating a canvas and drawing on it. First we need to [declare our custom UI element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml). In the initiation we need to create a subclass of [Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29). In this case, we will use [BoringLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/BoringLayout.html) which only supports text with a single line.

```
Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20,
    new int[]{bottom,top},
    new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);//Assumes bottom and top are colors defined above
textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
textPaint.setShader(textShader);
BoringLayout.Metrics boringMetrics=BoringLayout.isBoring(text, textPaint);
boringLayout=new BoringLayout(text, textPaint, 0, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
            0.0f, 0.0f, boringMetrics, false);
```

We then override `onMeasure` and `onDraw`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    setMeasuredDimension((int) textPaint.measureText(text), (int) textPaint.getFontSpacing());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    boringLayout.draw(canvas);
}
```

Our implementation of `onDraw` is at this point quite lazy (it completely ignores the measurement specs!, but so long as you guarantee that the view is given sufficent space, it should work okay.

Alternatively, it would be possible to inherit from a `Canvas` and override the `onPaint` method. If this is done, then unfortunately the anchor for text being drawn will always be on the bottom so we have to add `-textPaint.getFontMetricsInt().ascent()` to our y coordinate.

Answer (score 151):

```
TextView secondTextView = new TextView(this);
Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20,
            new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE},
            new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
secondTextView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

Comment: On my ICS device, this doesn't seem to work -- it is completely transparent. Anyone else seeing the same thing? The view is not hardware accelerated.

Comment: @Steve Prentice: may be y1 = 20 too short, so you cannot see any gradient, try : new LinearGradient(0,0,0,secondTextView.getPaint().getTextSize(),....) - maybe it will solve your problem

Comment: Fix this:    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP

Comment: @StevePrentice : I've come across the issue on OS 9.0 as well. Another reason may be that you need to specify the **alpha value** for the gradient color array. e.g Set one of the colors as 0xFF148CDC instead of  0x148CDC.

Answer (score 83):

I have used the top answer(@Taras) with a gradient of 5 colors, but there is a problem: the textView looks like that I have put a white cover on it. Here is my code and the screenshot.

```
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_tv);
        textView.setText("Tianjin, China".toUpperCase());

        TextPaint paint = textView.getPaint();
        float width = paint.measureText("Tianjin, China");

        Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, textView.getTextSize(),
                new int[]{
                        Color.parseColor("#F97C3C"),
                        Color.parseColor("#FDB54E"),
                        Color.parseColor("#64B678"),
                        Color.parseColor("#478AEA"),
                        Color.parseColor("#8446CC"),
                }, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        textView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

[image]

After many hours, I found out that I need to call `textView.setTextColor()` with the first color of the gradient. Then the screenshot:

[image]

Hope help someone!

Comment: Why are you making gradient from top left corner to bottom right corner? Shouldn't it be `LinearGradient(0, 0, width, 0, ...` instead for horizontal gradient?

Comment: @fdermishin : We copied this gradient effect from Instagram. 

Answer (score 18):

Here it is with multiline support as a one liner.  This should work for Buttons too.

```
Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0,0,0,textView.getLineHeight(),
                                  startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
textView.getPaint().setShader(shader);
```

Comment: Works, but for the height you might want to take into account letters that go below the actual line (like y, g, j, etc) and multiply the lineheight by 1.10f, e.g. `textView.getLineHeight() * 1.10f`.

Answer (score 10):

I've rolled up a library that encompasses both of these methods. You can create GradientTextView in XML or just use GradientTextView.setGradient(TextView textView...) to do it on a regular TextView object.

https://github.com/koush/Widgets

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin + coroutines version.

Extension for setting vertical gradient:

```
private fun TextView.setGradientTextColor(vararg colorRes: Int) {
    val floatArray = ArrayList<Float>(colorRes.size)
    for (i in colorRes.indices) {
        floatArray.add(i, i.toFloat() / (colorRes.size - 1))
    }
    val textShader: Shader = LinearGradient(
        0f,
        0f,
        0f,
        this.height.toFloat(),
        colorRes.map { ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), it) }.toIntArray(),
        floatArray.toFloatArray(),
        TileMode.CLAMP
    )
    this.paint.shader = textShader
}
```

Suspend extension. You need to wait for the view to change its height.

```
suspend fun View.awaitLayoutChange() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> { cont ->
val listener = object : View.OnLayoutChangeListener {
    override fun onLayoutChange(
        view: View?,
        left: Int,
        top: Int,
        right: Int,
        bottom: Int,
        oldLeft: Int,
        oldTop: Int,
        oldRight: Int,
        oldBottom: Int
    ) {
        view?.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this)
        cont.resumeWith(Result.success(Unit))
    }
}

addOnLayoutChangeListener(listener)
cont.invokeOnCancellation { removeOnLayoutChangeListener(listener) }
```

}

And usage:

```
lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
        binding.tvAmount.text = "Dumb text"
        binding.tvAmount.awaitLayoutChange()
        binding.tvAmount.setGradientTextColor(
            R.color.yellow,
            R.color.green
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple but somewhat limited solution would be to use these attributes:

```
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

I have used it on textfields where I want them to fade out if they get too long.

Answer (score 3):

**For Kotlin:**

```
val paint: TextPaint = textView.paint
    val width: Float = paint.measureText(holder.langs.text.toString())

    val textShader: Shader = LinearGradient(0f, 0f, width, holder.langs.textSize, intArrayOf(
            Color.parseColor("#8913FC"),
            Color.parseColor("#00BFFC")), null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
    holder.langs.paint.shader = textShader
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solved way. Implement with text span.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWFYr.png)

```java
class LinearGradientForegroundSpan extends CharacterStyle implements UpdateAppearance {
    private int startColor;
    private int endColor;
    private int lineHeight;

    public LinearGradientForegroundSpan(int startColor, int endColor, int lineHeight) {
        this.startColor = startColor;
        this.endColor = endColor;
        this.lineHeight = lineHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, lineHeight,
                startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
    }
}
```

Styled your gradient text.

```java
    SpannableString gradientText = new SpannableString("Gradient Text");
    gradientText.setSpan(new LinearGradientForegroundSpan(Color.RED, Color.LTGRAY, textView.getLineHeight()),
            0, gradientText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    sb.append(gradientText);
    sb.append(" Normal Text");
    textView.setText(sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice way to do it:

```
/**
 * sets a vertical gradient on the textView's paint, so that on its onDraw method, it will use it.
 *
 * @param viewAlreadyHasSize
 *            set to true only if the textView already has a size
 */
public static void setVerticalGradientOnTextView(final TextView tv, final int positionsAndColorsResId,
        final boolean viewAlreadyHasSize) {
    final String[] positionsAndColors = tv.getContext().getResources().getStringArray(positionsAndColorsResId);
    final int[] colors = new int[positionsAndColors.length];
    float[] positions = new float[positionsAndColors.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < positionsAndColors.length; ++i) {
        final String positionAndColors = positionsAndColors[i];
        final int delimeterPos = positionAndColors.lastIndexOf(':');
        if (delimeterPos == -1 || positions == null) {
            positions = null;
            colors[i] = Color.parseColor(positionAndColors);
        } else {
            positions[i] = Float.parseFloat(positionAndColors.substring(0, delimeterPos));
            String colorStr = positionAndColors.substring(delimeterPos + 1);
            if (colorStr.startsWith("0x"))
                colorStr = '#' + colorStr.substring(2);
            else if (!colorStr.startsWith("#"))
                colorStr = '#' + colorStr;
            colors[i] = Color.parseColor(colorStr);
        }
    }
    setVerticalGradientOnTextView(tv, colors, positions, viewAlreadyHasSize);
}

/**
 * sets a vertical gradient on the textView's paint, so that on its onDraw method, it will use it. <br/>
 *
 * @param colors
 *            the colors to use. at least one should exist.
 * @param tv
 *            the textView to set the gradient on it
 * @param positions
 *            where to put each color (fraction, max is 1). if null, colors are spread evenly .
 * @param viewAlreadyHasSize
 *            set to true only if the textView already has a size
 */
public static void setVerticalGradientOnTextView(final TextView tv, final int[] colors, final float[] positions,
        final boolean viewAlreadyHasSize) {
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final TileMode tile_mode = TileMode.CLAMP;
            final int height = tv.getHeight();
            final LinearGradient lin_grad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, colors, positions, tile_mode);
            final Shader shader_gradient = lin_grad;
            tv.getPaint().setShader(shader_gradient);
        }
    };
    if (viewAlreadyHasSize)
        runnable.run();
    else
        runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(tv, runnable);
}

public static void runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(final View view, final Runnable runnable) {
    final OnPreDrawListener preDrawListener = new OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            runnable.run();
            return true;
        }
    };
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener);
}
```

Also, if you wish to use a bitmap of the gradient, instead or a real one, use:

```
/**
 * sets an image for the textView <br/>
 * NOTE: this function must be called after you have the view have its height figured out <br/>
 */
public static void setBitmapOnTextView(final TextView tv, final Bitmap bitmap) {
    final TileMode tile_mode = TileMode.CLAMP;
    final int height = tv.getHeight();
    final int width = tv.getWidth();
    final Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
    final BitmapShader bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(temp, tile_mode, tile_mode);
    tv.getPaint().setShader(bitmapShader);
}
```

EDIT: Alternative to runJustBeforeBeingDrawn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136027/878126

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is to apply a text color before applying any shaders. As the author of the question posted:

> After many hours, I found out that I need to call textView.setTextColor() with the first color of the gradient. Then the screenshot:

What works is to have, for instance, a white color setup as text color in the first place. Then we can apply the shader, and it will be applied on top of the white so we will get the desired gradient color.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to do this without the TextView class extension.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val textGradientOnGlobalLayoutListener = object: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            textGradient.paint.shader = LinearGradient(0f, 0f,
                    textGradient.width.toFloat(),
                    textGradient.height.toFloat(),
                    color0, color1, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
            textGradient.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    }
    private val textGradient by lazy {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_gradient)
    }
    private val color0 by lazy {
        ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.purple_200)
    }
    private val color1 by lazy {
        ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.teal_200)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        textGradient.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(textGradientOnGlobalLayoutListener)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to draw the Gradient Text View

Sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzC7d.png

```
class GradientTextView : AppCompatTextView {
private var gradientShader: LinearGradient? = null
private var paint: Paint? = null

private val gradientColors = intArrayOf(
    context.getColor(R.color.colorGreen), //Start color 
    context.getColor(R.color.colorBlack) // End color
)

constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {
    init()
}

constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(
    context!!, attrs
) {
    init()
}

constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context!!, attrs, defStyleAttr
) {
    init()
}

private fun init() {
    // Set up the paint object
    paint = getPaint()
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val paint = paint
    val width = measuredWidth.toFloat()
    val height = (measuredHeight.toFloat() / 1.4).toFloat()

    if (gradientShader == null) {
        gradientShader = LinearGradient(
            0f, 0f, width, 0f,
            gradientColors,
            null,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )
    }

    paint?.shader = gradientShader
    canvas.drawText(text.toString().trim(), 0f, height, paint!!)
}
}
```

This view can be used the same as the Textview

```
<GradientTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/business"
    android:textSize="45sp"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
import com.sanne.MultiColorTextView;

MultiColorTextView textview= new MultiColorTextView(this);
textview.setText("SOME TEXT");
textview.setTextColor(/*INT ARRAY WITH YOUR COLOURS*/ );
```

The program sets a gradient colour across the textview and you can also set separate colours for particular text using

```
multiColorTextView.colorAll("A word");
```

MutliColorTextView from https://www.github.com/sanneemmanuel/MultiColorTextView

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with the linked library in your answer. Not doing so is spam.