# Android: Gradient Color for Button Text

Tags: android, button, text, colors, gradient

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text with gradient in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android)

I'm trying to make a button for my app with a white background and gradient-colored text.  However, everything I've found gives advice for making only the background a gradient color using a separate XML file. Can someone please tell me if it's possible to have only the text of a button colored with a gradient and how to do so?

Comment: int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; // red for the example
mButton.setColor(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors)); try it may be possible using it..i am not sure..

Answer (score 1):

Make a clickable textView with gradient color and set its background as you wish.
Follow the link specified by @SidharthLele.