# Alpha-gradient on Android

Tags: android, imageview, gradient, android-imageview, alpha-transparency

I need to create an alpha-gradient on the edge of the ImageView. Preferably using only XML.

[*Image for example*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q24wq.png)

Comment: also take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5088137/4270676 should also work for an ImageView.

Comment: @Lucker10 Yep. This is correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to code a custom ImageView if you want colorless transparency.

If your background is a static color, here's my preferred workaround:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image"/>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#00efefef"
                android:endColor="#ffefefef"
                android:angle="270"
                android:type="linear"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
```

perfect transperancy. Make sure that the View below gradient is actually below and not just touching Gradient shape View.

If you have main    **RelativeLayout,**    **ListView**   and    **View(Background:Gradient )**

make sure that **Gradient View** is on top, of the ListView, and not a side. If Your **gradient** is aside it will be transparent by **RelativeLayout** Background Color and not by **ListView** .

i hope you understand what i want to say.

Answer (score 2):

For transparency :

```
android:startColor="@null"
```

Or  you can use a 8-digit hex color like that :

```
android:startColor="#FF000000"
```

The first two FF are for the alpha of the color, 00 is fully transparent and FF opaque