# Add Wordart / Funky / Fancy Text Effects in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

[image: How to get these funky text effects on an android canvas]

I want to get these photo effects in my Livewallpaper.I searched through but it was no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw text with a custom font like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/Drawtextwithcustomfont.htm) example.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
paint.setTextSize(40);
Typeface chops = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ChopinScript.ttf");
paint.setTypeface(chops);
float text_x = 120;
float text_y = 120;
canvas.drawText("Hello", text_x, text_y, paint);
```

And then you can add effects to it like these stackoverflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text).

Comment: A neat and clean answer, but I need to ask is this the only resort ? Because I had thought about it initially but was confused with some effects like gradients like in the image shown above(2nd last row last column) so I will have to combine these effects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958111/how-to-set-gradient-as-the-text-color-of-a-textview