# Setting a gradient in a text

Tags: android, textview, gradient

I want this output:

[image]

The two colors are :

```
<color name="clrc2">#c27a1c</color>
    <color name="clrfe">#fee17f</color>
```

And i have tried this code :

```
Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0,100,10,100,
                new int[]{resources.getColor(R.color.clrc2),resources.getColor(R.color.clrfe),resources.getColor(R.color.clrc2)}
                ,new float[]{0.4f,0.2f,0.4f}, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        option_.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.clrc2));
        option_.getPaint().setShader( shader );
```

I am not achieving the desired result.

This is the result I get :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got the accurate gradient by this code :

```
Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(0, 8, 0, 18,
            new int[]{Color.parseColor("#c27a1c"), Color.parseColor("#fee17f")},
            new float[]{0, 1}, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
    option_.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.clrfe));
    option_.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

Ref from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16958396/5327912

Comment: can u explain why input : 0, 8, 0, 18?