# Make some part of a view transparent (related to his inner Y position)

Tags: java, android

I have to make a `TextView` that disappears progressively related to his Y coordinate (in a `ScrollView`).
The text should disappear progressively.

This means that the top of the letter (in the `TextView`) should have an alpha 0 and the bottom (of the same letter) should have an alpha 1.

I have to do this in my CustomeView, that is in a ScrollView. And make the textDisepear related to the scroll.

So how can i do this?

is this possible with a brush?

i have an image example:

[image]

i hope you'll be able to understand my problem..

Comment: I think this is the best answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Shader` for that:

```
Shader alphaShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, textHeight,
        new int[] {Color.parseColor("#ff000000"), Color.parseColor("#00000000")},
        new float[] {0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
textView.getPaint().setShader(alphaShader);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks
And can i use this with a RelativeLayout / LinearLayout / View / MyCustomeView ?

Comment: You can, but for a layout it will only work on it's background -- because it only works on stuff that the `View` draws itself. To fade children of a `RelativeLayout` this way, you'll need to assign a shader to each one of them, and tweak parameters based on their position. Also, if you're just looking to fade the topmost and lowest element edges in something scrollable, look into `android:fadingEdge` and `android:requiresFadingEdge` attributes