# Apply a gradient to text of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How to apply shadow as per above image? I used

```
android:ellipsize="none"
```

for ellipsize of text from TextView.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android ?

Comment: I want as per attached image.. :(

Comment: open link and try code, you got same result

Comment: @nisha.113a5 That's called a **gradient**, not a **shadow**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);         
        Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0,0, 60, 20,
                new int[]{Color.WHITE,Color.TRANSPARENT},
                new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);         
        txt.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

I guess all you need to adjust (if required) is those values like 60,20 in above.

I am attaching the screenshot of the result, for reference.[image]