# How do I achieve this Gradiant color if it possible at all?

Tags: android

I made this Icon in Photoshop, but now I want to make the gradiant in Android and use it as the `Textcolor` for a `Textview`

The colors and settings from Photoshop is:

Style: Linear

Angle: 90*

Colors: #00a8d9 (0%), #223595 (20%), #f1328f(40%), #ee3031(60%), #f9e63a(80%), #009958(100%)

The numbers in the parentes is the location value.

[image]

I have tried the following, but its only showing one color

```
LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(20,30,40,50, new int[]    {Color.parseColor("#00a8d9"), Color.parseColor("#223595"), Color.parseColor("#f1328f"), Color.parseColor("#ee3031"), Color.parseColor("#f9e63a"), Color.parseColor("#009958")},new float[]{0,0,0,0,0,0},
    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    textView.getPaint().setShader(linearGradient);
```

Comment: you can have as many colors as you want by using a `LinearGradient` as a `Shader` to your `Paint`

Comment: If you want shader for text - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android

Comment: @Dipalishah I have tried this and put all the colors, but it dosn't give me any gradiant effect, but only showing one color

Comment: Seems interesting! Can I know the reason for not using it as an imageview rather than a textview?

Comment: instead of `new float[]{0,0,0,0,0,0}` use `null`

Comment: @pskink Thanks! it works now

Comment: your params `20,30,40,50` are also wrong

Comment: @pskink Yes I just changed theese values too

Answer (score 0):

I managed to replicate the gradient from the picture to the code with this solution:

```
     textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fontcolorwhite);

    LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(60,-70,60,70, new  int[]{Color.parseColor("#00a8d9"), Color.parseColor("#4244b8"), Color.parseColor("#f1328f"), Color.parseColor("#ee3031"), Color.parseColor("#fde92d"), Color.parseColor("#009e54")},null,
    Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
    textView.getPaint().setShader(linearGradient);
```

Another problem is that the gradient dosn't look the same with different screen sizes. This will be in a another question

Answer (score -1):

You may Try this.

Try to set this as your view background colour and set colour as per your need.

```
 GradientDrawable rainbow = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                    new int[] {Color.RED, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED});

textview.setBackground(rainbow);
```

Comment: but `textview.setColor()` requires an int type