# Can we add a drawable to Textview textcolor?

Tags: android, textview

This is the drawable I am trying to give the textview as textcolor :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:centerX="46%"
        android:startColor="#FFc27a1c"
        android:centerColor="#FFfee17f"
        android:endColor="#FFc27a1c"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

But when i apply it as the text color, the text becomes blue in color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text with gradient in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android)

Comment: duplicate ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android