# Ripple effect on only textview text not background

Tags: android, textview, ripple

Before downvote this question first read my question proper.

I need ripple effect on textview click only for it's text not for its background.

I am using this

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

but it shows effect with its background. I have already used xml file using `ripple` tag but same thing happened.

So instead effect on background of textview with ripple effect how can i set it to only for its text?

Advanced help would be appreciated !

Comment: use `android:textColor="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` instead of background.

Comment: It will not work. By using that my desire text will not show and also not its color too.

Comment: You can change textColor on click but I doubt you can achieve some kind of ripple effect on text easily

Comment: I am wondering for it.

Comment: This ripple effect as is, is drawing above first available background. You will have write yourselft some custom animation. You can probably start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android to use gradient as textColor

Comment: Ripple animation or simple animation ??