# Issue of having blur gradient textcolor instead of clear gradient

Tags: android, textview, gradient

**Clarification**::
A gradient is set on textView and the eventual outcome is in **blur colour** like in the first picture. How might I accomplish gradient **without blur** in the accompanying code, like in the second picture?
[image: Fig11].
[image: Fig2]

```
 val paint: TextPaint =  binding!!.tvGetStarted.getPaint()
            val width = paint.measureText("Get Started")
    
    
            val textShader: Shader = LinearGradient(
                0F, 0F, width,  binding!!.tvGetStarted.getTextSize(), intArrayOf(
                    Color.parseColor("#F97C3C"),
                    Color.parseColor("#FDB54E"),
                    Color.parseColor("#64B678"),
                    Color.parseColor("#478AEA"),
                    Color.parseColor("#8446CC")
                ), null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
            )
            binding!!.tvGetStarted.getPaint().setShader(textShader)
```

Take references from [Text with gradient in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android) but nothing achieved desirably

Comment: It looks more translucent than blurred, yeah? Have you checked the alpha on the paint? Maybe try `paint.alpha = 255`, just to quickly test.

Comment: Yeah, that user states "I found out that I need to call `textView.setTextColor()` with the first color of the gradient.", which I believe is just resetting the alpha to opaque for them ('cause `#F97C3C` has implied `FF` alpha). IIRC, the primary text colors of several standard library themes have non-opaque alphas, which might be where that's coming from to begin with.

Comment: @MikeM. I tried and seems its better than before

Comment: I recently got around to testing this, and that alpha is coming from the theme color, but that test/quick-fix suggestion is not stable. If you do handle it in code, then `setTextColor()` is what you should use, though you can call it with any opaque color you like, since it's not really used. If you don't want to handle it in code, you can set the `android:textColor` attribute in the layout XML similarly. Just FYI. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM.Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This answer - [Text with gradient in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680607/text-with-gradient-in-android), already show you need to call `textView.setTextColor()` with the first color of the gradient i.e. `#F97C3C`

After adding `textView.setTextColor()` you will get output as 2nd output.

I tried this solution and it works for me, output for solution.
[image]

Comment: There is no point in repeating an answer. You could've simply commented that.